# How to remove weblinks component rests after updating from J 3.3 to 3.4?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x, joomla-3.4, update, weblinks

I have installed the update from Joomla 3.3 to 3.4. After that, the Weblinks component showed an update, which could not be installed due to a missing database table.

Furthermore, the weblinks entry in the extension menu showed a 404 - component missing.
I then proceeded to deinstall the weblinks, but it says:

> JFolder: :delete: The Path is no Folder! Pfad:
> /html/joomla/administrator/components/com_weblinks
>
> JFolder: :delete: The Path is no Folder! Pfad:
> /html/joomla/components/com_weblinks
>
> Componentdeinstallation: Deinstallation not possible, please remove
> manually.
>
> Packagedeinstallation: Manifest-File not found.

How do I remove the rests of the weblinks package from my Joomla installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Before attempting anything below, make sure you have a working backup of your complete site, just in case.

**FILES:**

First check for any files in your Joomla installation. Using FTP look at and remove the whole folders (if found) in the following locations:

> - administrator/components/com_weblinks
> - components/com_weblinks
> - modules/mod_weblinks
> - plugins/search/weblinks
> - plugins/finder/weblinks

**DATABASE:**
Then with a database tool, like PHPmyAdmin, connect to your database and look at the following tables:

> `#__extensions`

look for any rows `where name LIKE '%weblinks%'` and delete them. This will delete all references of the package/component/module/plugins of the weblinks.

> `#__categories`

look for any rows `where extension = 'com_weblinks'` and delete them. This will clear your categories table from any weblinks categories.

> `#__assets`

look for any rows  `where name LIKE '%com_weblinks%'` and delete them.
This will delete the asset for the component itself and also any possible categories of the weblinks component, that still have an asset in the assets table.

> `#__menu`

look for any rows `where path LIKE 'Weblinks%'` and delete them. This will delete any references to the component in the admin menu.

> `#__weblinks`

Delete the whole table.

I think I have included everything... as said at the top of my answer have a tested backup, in case something goes wrong while you are deleting folders and data in your database.

You might be also better if you try all these at a testing site.

Comment: Thank you for the fast and detailed response. I followed your instructions and I can not find any trace of the weblinks in my Joomla any more. Much thanks again for your help!